# WSO2 Remember me Check - Session is not killed on Browers close

Tags: session, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 5.0 SP1. We have set  (to 1 day) in  and is working as expected. The problem we are facing is that the session remains active in WSO2 on browser restart. Is there a way to create new session whenever the user restarts the browser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the idea of `Remember Me`. It helps to remember the cookie for you.  Therefore it is stored in the browser till it expired. It does not expired when browser is closed. If you need to expire the session when browser it closed,  you can not use remember me option.